# GAS script to copy a tab from an excel fil attached to an incoming email and pasting it into a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GAS that needs to:

1. find the most recent email with a specific label
2. open the attaced excel file and copy the tab named 'reservations'
3. paste the data into the 'mews' tab of a google sheet

The below code errors at line 45 "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp."

```
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('sbh_channel');
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:inbox label:sbh_channel", 0, 1);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[1];
   Logger.log("Message Subject: " + message.getSubject());
  
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  if (attachments.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
      var attachment = attachments[i];
      Logger.log("Attachment Name: " + attachment.getName());
      Logger.log("Attachment Type: " + attachment.getContentType());
      Logger.log("Attachment Size: " + attachment.getSize());
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log("No attachments found.");
  }

  //Find the Excel attachment in the email
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  var excelFile;
  for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    var attachment = attachments[i];
    if (attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL) {
      excelFile = attachment;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!excelFile) {
    Logger.log("No Excel attachment found in email.");
    return;
  }
  Logger.log("Excel attachment found.");

  //Get the spreadsheet ID from the attachment file name
  var spreadsheetId = excelFile.getName().match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  if (!spreadsheetId) {
    Logger.log("Could not extract spreadsheet ID from attachment file name.");
    return;
  }
  spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId[0];
  Logger.log("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId);

  //Open the Excel file and get the data from the "Reservations" tab
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)[0];
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Reservations");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log("Data loaded from Excel file.");

  //Open the Mews Google Sheets file and paste the data into the "Mews" sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1DLCn9mwhwlKD6eCDGWVA119X_CL-zPOnQbPk_ncaDtE");
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Mews");
  sheetName.getRange(2, 3, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  Logger.log("Data pasted to Mews sheet.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About `var spreadsheetId = excelFile.getName().match(/[-\w]{25,}/);` of `Get the spreadsheet ID from the attachment file name` in your script, in your situation, I'm worried that if the Spreadsheet ID is invalid, such an error occurs.

If you want to retrieve the values from the XLSX data of the attachment file, I thought that [this method in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75706380) might be useful. When this method is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

### Usage:

#### 1. Install SheetJS library.

Please copy the script of the SheetJS library from https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js, and paste the script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and save the script.

In this case, I would like to recommend the following flow.

1. Add a new script to the script editor. For example, the filename is `SheetJS`.
2. Copy and paste the script of https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js to the added script file, and save the script.

#### 2. Modified script:

After you installed the library, please modify your showing script as follows.

##### From:

```
//Get the spreadsheet ID from the attachment file name
var spreadsheetId = excelFile.getName().match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
if (!spreadsheetId) {
  Logger.log("Could not extract spreadsheet ID from attachment file name.");
  return;
}
spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId[0];
Logger.log("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheetId);

//Open the Excel file and get the data from the "Reservations" tab
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId)[0];
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Reservations");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
Logger.log("Data loaded from Excel file.");
```

##### To:

```
var book = XLSX.read(new Uint8Array(attachment.getBytes()), { type: "array" });
var csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(book.Sheets["Reservations"]);
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
if (data.length == 0) return;
```

- When this modified script is run, the values are retrieved from "Reservations" in the XLSX data of the attachment file, and the retrieved values are put into your Spreadsheet using your script.

### Note:

- In this script, if you don't want to copy and paste the SheetJS library to the script editor, you can also install it with the following script. But, in this case, the process cost becomes high. Please be careful about this.

  ```js
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-latest/package/dist/xlsx.full.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText());
  ```

### Reference:

- [SheetJS CE](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/)